# In angularjs ionic autofocus the transition is jerky and stutters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

In angularjs ionic, the input field autofocus the transition is jerky and stutters. I found solution by adding a body class with -webkit-transition: none but this also disable my transition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a version of Ionic Framework prior to 1.1.1 and iOS 9? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the version of Ionic Framework you are using is not compatible with iOS 9. In the future, if iOS 9 is a long distant memory... it's likely because Ionic Framework needs to be updated for the latest version of iOS. See the following:

- [iOS 9 Potential Breaking Change](http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/)
- [Preparing for iOS 9](http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/)

Note that you no longer need to apply the patches manually for iOS 9. Instead, you can upgrade your Ionic Framework to [1.1.1 "yttrium-yeti"](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases/tag/v1.1.1) or later.